# App wont run in Android Studio 2.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to run a very basic code but for some reason, its not installing and it takes an awfully long time to run the app with no results.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
```

I feel like there is an update or something I missing but I am newbie so its hard for me to pinpoint. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: please share your `build.gradle` file and any errors that you're getting.

Comment: This is the error message in the event log "com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlProcessingInstructionImpl cannot be cast to com.intellij.psi.xml.XmlAttribute"

Comment: you try to make clean to project?
Build -> clean project

Comment: @OmriLugasi I did. It might be worth mentioning that this started happening after I upgraded to Marshmellow.

Comment: @isacc Abraham please post your code here. and your build.gradle